# strange delete behavior for two OneToMany relationships on a junction table using JPA for spring

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many, one-to-many

[EER diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHr62.jpg)

Base on the EER diagram, technically the `Task` and `TodoList` are of `ManyToMany` relationship, but instead of using a junction table I created this two `OneToMany` relationships from `Task` to `TaskList` and from `TodoList` to `TaskList`.

I tried to associate `ListTask` with only `Task` or `TodoList`, then attempted to delete the `ListTask` by clearing the reference list in `Task` or `TodoList`, then persist the `Task` or `TodoList`, which works fine, `ListTask` is gone and the updated `Task` or `TodoList` entity is clear of `ListTask`.

However when I associate the `ListTask` with both `Task` and `TodoList` then tried to delete, strangely when deleting from the `Task` side, no delete query is generated by the hibernate. Until I delete from `TodoList` side then it finally worked. I swapped the order of calling `list.clear()` on `TodoList` and `Task` then `TodoList` will first deleted the `ListTask`, left `Task` with no `ListTask` to handle and created an error.

I've tried all I can to make the `TodoList` and `ListTask` identical, still no luck. The delete action will work for one side and stick to it. I know the tables design aren't perfect, but really trying to find out why and how hibernate picks side to do the delete.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "task")
public class Task {

    private int taskId;

    // other properties ...

    private List<ListTask> listTasks = new ArrayList<>();

    public Task() {    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "taskid")
    public int getTaskId() {
        return taskId;
    }

    public void setTaskId(int taskId) {
        this.taskId = taskId;
    }

    // other getters and setters ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "task", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    public List<ListTask> getListTasks() {
        return listTasks;
    }

    public void setListTasks(List<ListTask> listTasks) {
        this.listTasks = listTasks;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "todolist")
public class TodoList {

    private int id;

    // other properties ...

    private List<ListTask> listTasks = new ArrayList<>();

    public TodoList() {     }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "todolistid")
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    // other getters and setters ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "todoList", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    public List<ListTask> getListTasks() {
        return listTasks;
    }

    public void setListTasks(List<ListTask> listTasks) {
        this.listTasks = listTasks;
    }
}

@Test
public void deleteTest() {

    Task task = ...;
    TodoList todoList = ...;
    ListTask listTask = new ListTask();

    // Associate ListTask with Task first.

    listTask.setTask(task);
    task.getListTasks().add(listTask);
    task = taskRepository.save(task);

    // get the persisted ListTask then associate with TodoList

    listTask = task.getListTasks().toArray(new ListTask[1])[0];
    listTask.setTodoList(todoList);
    todoList.getListTasks().add(listTask);
    todoList = todoListRepository.save(todoList);

    // Start trying different deletions

    task.getListTasks().clear();
    taskRepository.save(task);

    // At this step hibernate only generated select queries, no delete ones, thus no ListTask got removed.

    todoList.getListTasks().clear();
    todoListRepository.save(todoList);

    // At this step hibernate finally generated "delete from listtask where listtaskid=? ..." thus removed the ListTask.
}
```